# creating new prototype functions vs function references

Tags: javascript, optimization, game-engine

Javascript gives many options on how to do very similar things, so sometimes it's hard to decide whats best.

I have code where i can either create functions once as a global object, then reference them, or add functions to the prototype of the instances im creating.

so i'd like to know whats better practice and has a lower memory overhead (i'm making a game engine so i can't have the garbage collector pausing often, and avoid new objects as much as possible);

is using a reference to a function defined globally (actually its part of an object where i store "globals" to not pollute window) actually worse, i'm worried that adding functions to a prototype means every object I instantiate with "new" is creating new functions when i can just reference to a function once instead.

Comment: No, adding methods to the constructor's prototype will share the same function for all instances. It would be different if you added the method to `this` inside the constructor, which would create a different privileged method for each instance.

Comment: Depending on your circumstances, the overhead of having those local methods may be negligible -- or possibly even less than the overhead of the lookup on the prototype chain. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047747/javascript-setting-object-properties-with-value-type-in-the-prototype/16047975#16047975